# How do I get the Universal Link to redirect to my Capacitor iOS app? SWCErrorDomain error 8

Tags: ios, capacitor, ios-universal-links, universal-link

I'm running my Capacitor app on my iPad on Developer mode and I haven't been able to get the Universal Link working.

`https://my-domain.com//.well-known/apple-app-site-association` in browser and via `curl` correctly returns the file.

running `sudo swcutil dl -d https://my-domain.com --verbose`

returns

```
SWCErrorDomain 8 {
    Domain: "<_SWCDomain 0x600002c92d80> https",
    Line: "532",
    Function: "-[SWCDownloader(Private) _downloadAASAFileForDomain:applicationIdentifier:downloadRoute:discretionary:completionHandlers:]_block_invoke"
}
```

I made my way down through here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3155-debugging-universal-links#Host-and-verify-your-AASA

I continued onto the next section, and my app is showing up in the `swcutil_show.txt` file:

```
Service:              applinks
App ID:               78A4MS27Y9.com.my-domain
App Version:          1.0
App PI:               <LSPersistentIdentifier 0xbd200b170> { v = 0, t = 0x8, u = 0x7ac, db = 43C6B197-DCC8-4122-BDD7-54D3206CC9D8, {length = 8, bytes = 0xac07000000000000} }
Domain:               my-domain.com
Patterns:             {"/":"/*"}
User Approval:        unspecified
Site/Fmwk Approval:   approved
Flags:                
Last Checked:         2024-03-20 14:28:43 +0000
Next Check:           2024-03-25 13:46:07 +0000
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!